# Can't get manualControls work for Flexslider plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to change the markup of the flexslider plugin, but I can't get it work. I was wondering how [this theme from themezilla](http://demo.themezilla.com/blox/) has set the thumbnails of the slider outside the `.flexslider` div that contains the showed images. What I want is inside the `slider` container the big images and `prev` and `next`
 buttons. Outside that div the new div with the `thumbnail previews`.

It's from the yellow section, the third one, with the folder image.

**Themezilla code**
I look had there code and saw this:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $("#slider-74").imagesLoaded( function() {
                    $("#slider-74").flexslider({
                        slideshow: false,
                        controlNav: false,
                        prevText: "&#8250;",
                        nextText: "&#8249;",
                        namespace: 'zilla-',
                        smoothHeight: true,
                                                        controlNav: true,
                            manualControls: '#zilla-thumbs-nav-74 li',
                                                    start: function(slider) {
                            if( typeof slider.container === 'object' ) {
                                slider.container.click(function(e) {
                                    if( !slider.animating ) {
                                        slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

I add some properties to my code:

```
// Gallery Flexslider
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        slideshow: false,
        manualControls: '#thumbs-nav li',
        start: function(slider) {
            if( typeof slider.container === 'object' ) {
                slider.container.click(function(e) {
                    if( !slider.animating ) {
                        slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, there is noting changed. See image below:
[image: Changed noting of the HTML markup]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I maybe missing it, but I don't see a slider on that theme page.

Comment: My apologies, I have edit my question. It from the yellow section, the third one. The white section with the thumbnails. @zgood

Answer (score 0):

I think how it's suppose to be setup is that you have 1 flexslider that shows your full sized images and then create another flexslider carousel that has your thumbs.  Then on your carousel flexslider set the option `asNavFor` to the `id` of your first flexslider. They will be 2 separate components, but the carousel will be bound to the first slider because of this option being set.

Here is a demo of it being done with FlexSlider 2: [Demo](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html)

I am pretty sure you can achieve this with the earlier version of FlexSlider because it does have the `asNavFor` property (see the doc [here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties)).

**asNavFor**: *Selector* Turn the slider into a thumbnail navigation for another slider.

Also, I think you need to set the `sync` property of your first flexslider to the `id` of the second one.

**sync**: *Selector* Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider.